# Que heranças do gênero neutro tem o português?

Tags: mudanças-históricas

O latim tinha três gêneros: o masculino (*homo*), o feminino (*mulier*) e o neutro (*alcohol*).  Há algum traço no português que advenha do gênero neutro latino?

Um gênero gramatical é uma característica muito forte, então, acho difícil não haver nada.

Comment: https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/os-generos-masculino-feminino-e-neutro/20733

Comment: Como *isto*, *isso* e *aquilo* — e talvez *tudo*?

Comment: @tchrist, eu estou sendo bem geral, tirando substantivos normais, como *mar*, que era neutro, pois, isto já é obviíssimo. Não sabia de *tudo*. Obrigado.

Comment: Em português, algumas palavras do Latim que eram femininas viraram masculinas. Outras que eram masculinas ficaram femininas. Como o português só tem esses dois gêneros, se supõe que uma palavra precisa ser uma ou outra. Para mim, isto, isso e aquilo não contam porque não se pode dizer: um aquilo ou um isto ou um tudo.

Answer (score 1):

Todo substantivo da língua portuguesa é acompanhado de gênero. Alguns substantivos, porém, possuem seu gênero inferido através do artigo. Por exemplo, os substantivos relacionados à cargos, terminados em "ente":

- Superintendente
- Presidente
- Assistente
- Tenente.

Ou seja, eu posso dizer tanto "O assistente" quanto "A assistente", as duas formas estão corretas, porém não existe forma neutra: a palavra necessariamente deve ser acompanhada de artigo, e o artigo sempre terá um gênero: masculino ou feminino.

Alguns pronomes e preposições não possuem gênero, como "e", "de", "tudo", "nada", etc. Isso não significa que possuem gênero neutro, uma vez que não são acompanhados de nenhum indicador de gênero.

Ou seja, por mais que seja possível encontrar na Língua Portuguesa palavras que possam ser masculinas ou femininas (mas não os dois ao mesmo tempo) e palavras que não possuem gênero, não existem termos reconhecidos na norma atual que aceitam algum tipo de alternativa ou variação correspondente à um terceiro gênero especificamente neutro.

Vale notar que, com o advento da Internet e o crescimento de movimentos socias que questionam a não-neutralidade de gênero, foram desenvolvidos pronomes intitulados como "neutros", como "elu", "elx", "el@", "meninx", "amigues", etc. Estes termos, apesar de eventualmente presentes em textos empresariais, políticos e até mesmo acadêmicos, não são reconhecidos por nenhuma grande instituição da Língua Portuguesa e são raramente utilizados em documentos oficiais com validez jurídica. Também vale notar que vários destes termos não são utilizados na língua falada por não possuírem pronúncia definida.

Dito isso, não podemos afirmar que existem gêneros neutros na Língua Portuguesa, mas certamente existem propostas para incluí-los na norma, o que aparentemente não acontecerá tão cedo.

Comment: Evandro Teixeira, obrigado pela resposta, mas eu não perguntava sobre esse gênero neutro, artificial, mas, sim, do gênero neutro que tinha o latim. E, como o latim veio do latim, queria saber quais eram suas herança ao português. Outra coisa, acho que nem todo substantivo tem gênero, como *Portugal*.